# [Java with Docker-compose]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/data/17.txt (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, docker, file, docker-compose

My Java application which use docker-compose can't find root path in Linux. I guess that something is wrong with volume's path. Can you help me please?

```
Cannot save user's book: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/data/17.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Method:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity saveBook(MultipartFile file, String filename) {
        try {
            file.transferTo(new File("/var/lib/data/" + fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new LibraryException("Cannot save user's book: " + e);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  mysql-log:
    driver: local
  mysql-conf:
    driver: local
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

services:
  dictionary_app_prod:
    container_name: dictionary_app_prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8082
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/data:/var/lib/data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- /var/lib/data:/var/lib/data
```

Check if it is correct, above line reads, from host absolute `/var/lib/data` path mount to container `/var/lib/data`

You can read more [details](http://blog.code4hire.com/2018/06/define-named-volume-with-host-mount-in-the-docker-compose-file/) about host mount in the docker-compose.